# [RVIZ2] Load configuration at launch

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to load an existing configuration for RVIZ2 from command line, but it seems that it is not possible, differently from RVIZ in ROS1.

Does RVIZ2 support command line parameters?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304637/%5Brviz2%5D-load-configuration-at-launch/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-10-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer was simple: `rviz2 -h`

```
Options:
  -h, --help                             Displays this help.
  -d, --display-config <display_config>  A display config file (.rviz) to load
```

---

Originally posted by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) with karma: 541 on 2018-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2020-10-18**:
Hi, Have you tried the same from a launch file? This doesn't work for me:

```
Node(package='rviz2', executable='rviz2', name="rviz2", output='screen', arguments=['-d '+rviz_path])
```

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-07-03**:
Note it should be `arguments=['-d', rviz_path]` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ros2/rviz/issues/627)